# How to append closing option tag for the first option in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here i am loading the data to the dropdown dynamically from the service, but when the data gets loaded to the dropdown the first child doesn't have the closing `</option>` rest every child has closing `</option>` tag.

I am trying to add the closing `</option>` for the first child through jQuery. how can I do it?

here is how the HTML looks.

```
<select id="myDropDown">
  <option class="" value="LC">LC
  <option class="" value="LC1">LC1</option>
  <option class="" value="LC2">LC2</option>
</select>
```

here's what I have tried.

```
$('#myDropDown').find('option').each(function(i){
  if(i!=0) 
    $(this).before('</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in JS is pointless, as JS runs ***after*** the DOM has been loaded. Therefore the browser's HTML renderer will already have fixed the broken syntax by appending the missing `</option>` for you.

If you check this snippet in the DOM inspector you'll see what I'm talking about in action; the closing tag has been added in for you:

```html
<select id="myDropDown">
  <option class="" value="LC">LC
  <option class="" value="LC1">LC1</option>
  <option class="" value="LC2">LC2</option>
</select>
```

Aside from that it's not possible as you can only insert whole elements in to the DOM, not closing tags.

If you have broken HTML then you need to fix it at the source, not through JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <select class="form-control" >
         <option selected disabled="disabled">select category</option>
              @foreach (var p in Model.Models)
                {
                <option value="@p.ID">@p.value</option>
                }
     </select>
```

Do this if you are using Model Directly  from the server

```
<select class="form-control" id="yourid" name="name">
   <option selected disabled>--Select Whatever--</option>
</select>
```

then in your script, if you are using ajax call to fetch the data, do this to append the other options

```
$('#yourid').append('<option value=' + res.ID + '>' + res.Name + '</option>');
```